# Accessing Azure Key Vault from Native Application

Tags: .net, azure, azure-keyvault

I have a .Net Application published to an Azure Web App Service (Native Application) 
and I want to get access to my Azure Key Vault from there.
I've already tried this: [Accessing Key Vault from Native App](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kv/2016/09/17/accessing-key-vault-from-a-native-application/)

but it only works when running the app locally and fails when running in the Azure Web App Service, I get this error:

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

And it is thrown in this method:

```cs
await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://vault.azure.net", 
                                ClientId, 
                                new Uri(ClientRedirectURI), 
                                new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto));
```

Any other way to get access to my Key Vault from a Native Application?
Tutorials like "Accesss Key Vault form a Web App" does not work for me since I don't have a ClientSecretID.

Thanks!

Comment: I think two things are being mistaken for one another here... A Native Application is an application like a Console or Windows application. So in short: you _cannot_ have a native app installed on an App Service. "Native client apps differ from web apps because they are installed on a device, while web apps are accessed through a browser."

Comment: "Tutorials like 'Accesss Key Vault form a Web App' does not work for me since I don't have a ClientSecretID." Register your application as a Web App and create one?

Comment: Thanks for the answer  @rickvdbosch .
I'm following this tutorial 
[link] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers [link]
And it says I have to use a Native app.
I'll try using a Web App.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

In your case, it need to prompt interface to enter username and password to get credital.

But the WebApp is a [sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox). The sandbox prevents access to all out-of-proc COM servers.

As  rickvdbosch mentioned that you could registry an Azure AD WebApp to get the clientId and secretkey. More information please refer to this [toturial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application). The following is the demo code how to access keyvault.

```
  public static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string tenantId,string appId,string secretKey)
    {

        var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId);
        ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(appId, secretKey);
        var tokenResponse =await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://vault.azure.net", clientCredential); //KeyVault resource : https://vault.azure.net
        var accessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
        return accessToken;
    }

    var kv = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(GetAccessToken));
```

We also could use the Azure Web [MSI function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/overview) to do that. You also could get how to access keyvault code from this [toturial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-managed-service-identity)

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
// ...
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
string accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/");
// OR
var kv = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
```

Comment: I've published my application to a new Azure Web App Service and I used the first code you mention in your answer and it worked perfectly!!! Thanks!